# Hide or Display column based on group visibilty expression

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

Currently working on an SSRS report in which there is a parameter "Display by Order" set to false as default. Within the body of the report, I would like to set the group expression to display the Column order if Parameter "Display by Order" is true otherwise do not display the column. I am unsure what the expression would be for this. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

The **Hidden** expression for the Column Visibility should be something like:

```
=Not Parameters!DisplayByOrder.Value
```

This just flips the parameter value, i.e. if the user selects `True`, the **Hidden** property should be `False`.

**More details as requested**

Add a Boolean parameter called `DisplayByOrder`.

[image]

I created a simple table with two columns.

[image]

Set the **Column Visibility** for the second column by right-clicking the top of the column to bring up its properties, then using the above expression:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Now the column is hidden/shown by the parameter selection as required:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks that works. But I will also need to change the grouping properties correct...? because there are currently three columns on the report Customer, Order and Revenue. A Customer can currently have more than 1 Order. So How can I change the grouping properties when the column is hidden/displayed.

Comment: It's really tough to be exact without more information - there is nothing in the question that describes your data or exactly how your output should change based on the parameter. Instead of grouping on a specific field, let's call it `order`, you can group on an expression like `=IIf(Parameters!DisplayByOrder.Value, Fields!order.Value, Nothing)`, which only applies grouping if a certain value is selected. Ideally, if you have multiple issues you should separate these and ask one SO question per issue.

Comment: I see you've raised another question for your grouping issue. Since you say this solved your main issue, i.e. hiding columns, please considering setting this answer as accepted: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

Hi try with something like this

```
IIf(Parameters!DisplayByOrder.Value = False, True, False)
```

Comment: Select column -> right click -> column visibility (menu item)-> then add your expression