# Grouping Expression based on hidden/ shown column

Tags: ssrs-2008, reportbuilder3.0

Question based from this: [Hide columns based on group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19909254/hide-or-display-column-based-on-group-visibilty-expression/19909352?noredirect=1#comment29624150_19909352)

I have the column which is displayed and hidden based on the Boolean Parameter (Display by Order) True or False.

The columns in the report are the following:

```
Customer         Order        Charge1      Charge2    Charge3
CNI              XHA156        200.00       150.00      50.00
CNI              TY156         100.00       200.00      100.00
LSI              UXYH          100.00       100.00      100.00
```

This is the columns and table displayed when Display by Order is selected as True. 
However, when it is selected as False, the following is shown:

```
Customer        Charge1      Charge2    Charge3
CNI             200.00       150.00      50.00
LSI             100.00       100.00      100.00
```

However, what it should display is the following:

```
Customer        Charge1      Charge2    Charge3
CNI             300.00       350.00      150.00
LSI             100.00       100.00      100.00
```

The row grouping expression that currently have set is the following:

```
=IIF(Parameters!Displayorder.Value=true, Fields!customer.Value & Fields!deal.Value, Fields!customer.Value)
```

However, this does not seem to aggregate the charges. Please let me know how I can modify this report to produce the required output. Help will be immensely appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the same data as your example:

[image]

I have a simple table based on this:

[image]

Note that I have one group and I am displaying a header row for this group. As such, all the different charge fields are using the `Sum` aggregate.

The group has two grouping items:

[image]

The expression for the second item is:

```
=IIf(Parameters!DisplayByOrder.Value, Fields!Order.Value, Nothing)
```

This expression is saying that if the parameter is `True`, include grouping by the `Order` field, otherwise no grouping.

I've also hidden the `Order` column based on the parameter selection.

Works OK for me when run:

[image]

[image]